# Angular reactive forms , populate nested formArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xPP.png)I have a JSON object with structure,

```
{
  "activityField": "string",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "postalCode": 0,
      "reference": "string",
      "region": "string",
      "street": "string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "code": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "domainName": "string",
  "groups": [
    {
      "defaultGroup": true,
      "name": "string",
      "prestationNames": [
        "string"
      ]

    }
  ],
  "name": "string",
  "principalAddress": {
    "postalCode": 0,
    "region": "string",
    "street": "string",
    "type": "string"
  }

}
```

everything works fine except for the nested array prestationsNames in groups array,
 each array of group have an array of prestationNames that needs to be populated form the backend.

My question are how to populate the the arrayFrom prestationNames  ?
how to bind it properly in the html?
how to get the values of the data and display them in the chekbox label and when clicking the value should be inserted not true or false

I have tried hardcoding the list of data and it worked , but that's not what i need.

I'm lost , can anyone help?

.ts file :

```
export class AddSocieteComponent implements OnInit {
  addSocieteForm: FormGroup;
  arrayOfadresses: { street: String; postalCode: String; region: String }[];
  numberOfAdresses: number = 0;
  listOfPrestation = [];

//hardcoded for now
  prestations = [
    { id: 1, name: "plomberie" },
    { id: 2, name: "chaud-froid" },
    { id: 3, name: "electricité" }
  ];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private societeServ: SocieteService,
    private serviceServ: ServiceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //get list of prestation when component is intialized
    this.serviceServ.getAllCatgories().subscribe(data => {
      this.listOfPrestation = data;
      console.log(this.listOfPrestation);
    });

    this.initForm();
    console.log(this.groups);
    console.log("pres", this.groupsControls[0].get("prestationNames"));
  }

  initForm() {
    //create controls for chekboxes
    let chekControls = this.prestations.map(element => {
      return this.formBuilder.control(element.name);
    });
    console.log("check", chekControls);
    this.addSocieteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ["", [Validators.required]],
      code: ["", [Validators.required, codeSocieteValidator]],
      activityField: ["", [Validators.required]],
      description: ["", [Validators.required]],
      domainName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      addresses: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      groups: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ["", [Validators.required]],
          defaultGroup: [false, []],
          prestationNames: this.formBuilder.array([])
        })
      ]),
      principalAddress: this.formBuilder.group({
        street: ["", [Validators.required]],
        postalCode: ["", [Validators.required, postalCodeValidator]],
        region: ["", [Validators.required]]
      })
    });
  }

  //clear field
  revert() {
    this.addSocieteForm.reset();
  }

  get prestationNames(): FormArray {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("prestationNames") as FormArray;
  }

  get prestationNamesControls() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("prestationNames")["controls"];
  }

  //get principal adress fields
  get principalAdress() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("principalAddress") as FormGroup;
  }

  // get controls for principal adress fields
  get principalAdressControls() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("principalAddress")["controls"];
  }

  // get form controls
  get f() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.controls;
  }

  // get adresses formArray
  get addresses(): FormArray {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("addresses") as FormArray;
  }

  // get groups formArray
  get groups(): FormArray {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("groups") as FormArray;
  }

  // get controls for groups formArray
  get groupsControls() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("groups")["controls"];
  }

  get asdressControls() {
    return this.addSocieteForm.get("addresses")["controls"];
  }

  addAdress() {
    if (this.numberOfAdresses < 2) {
      const item = {
        street: "",
        postalCode: "",
        region: ""
      };
      this.arrayOfadresses.push(item);
      this.addresses.push(this.formBuilder.group(item));
      this.numberOfAdresses++;
    } else {
      alert("nombre maximum d'adresse possible atteints");
    }
    console.log(this.addresses.controls);
  }

  // remove adress from aderesses formArray
  removeAdress(index) {
    this.addresses.removeAt(index);
    this.numberOfAdresses--;
  }

  // add a group as formArray
  addGroup() {
    const newGroup = {
      name: "",
      defaultGroup: false,
      prestationNames: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control("")])
    };
    this.groups.push(this.formBuilder.group(newGroup));
  }

  //remove group from groups formArray
  removeGroup(index) {
    this.groups.removeAt(index);
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    console.log(this.addSocieteForm.value);
    // save the company and subscribe to data
    this.societeServ.addCompany(this.addSocieteForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

the html part that concerns groups and prestationNames:

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="groups">
                 <div *ngFor="let group of groups.controls; let i=index"
                 [formGroup]="groups.controls[i]" class="row">
                         <div class="col">
                           <div class="form-group mt-4">
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label><input formControlName="defaultGroup" type="checkbox">groupe par defaut</label>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="col">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="name"> Nom groupe</label>
                              <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text">
                           </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="col" formArrayName="prestationNames">
                             <div *ngFor="let prestation of group.get('prestationNames').controls; let nameIndex=index"

                             >
                              <div class="col-4">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input [formControlName]="nameIndex" type="checkbox">{{prestations[nameIndex].name}}</label>
                                  </div>

                             </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                         </div>
                         <div class="col mt-2">
                           <div class="form-group">
                           <button
                          type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default mt-4 add-remove-button group-button"
                            (click)="removeGroup(i)"
                          >
                            -
                          </button>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>

               </div>
```

Comment: Since you are getting data from API try to create form inside subscribe

Comment: is this possible ?

Comment: another question when the chekbox is not selected the data is saved with false instead of the element value , i want it not to be inserted when the chekbnox is not selected

Comment: Have you tried to create form inside subscribe block?

Comment: i mouved the initForm in the subscribe and it worked , my issue now is when a chebox is not selected i dont want to store it in the array

Comment: I think that,when you refered to prestationNames is **formGroupName**, not formControlName: `[formGroupName]="nameIndex"`

Comment: i changed it like you said and it worked too , but when submiting the form all the values are inserted even when the chekbox isn't checked can explain to me ? i new  to reactive forms and it's confusing :(

Comment: remove the value which are false in checkbox array